# What does +(?!\d) in regex mean?

Tags: regex

I have also seen it as +$.

I am using

```
$(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
```

To convert 10000 into 10,000 etc.

I think I understand everything else:

- (\d) - find number
- (?=\d{3}) - if followed by 3 numbers
- '+' - don't stop after first find
- (?!\d) - starting from the last number?
- /g - for the whole string
- ,"$1," - replace number with self and comma

Comment: @SeanKenny Can you please explain [this regexp](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). I can't understand it, but I use it.

Comment: @SeanKenny because I know what it does & works, and at least I am trying to fully understand it by asking here, I didn't have to!

Comment: I meant how did you write the Regex without knowing what it did, but that seems like a silly question now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're slightly misreading it:

> - (?=\d{3}) - if followed by 3 numbers

Note that the regexp is actually:

```
(?=(\d{3})+
```

i.e. you've missed an open paren. The entire of the following:

```
(\d{3})+(?!\d)
```

is within the `(?= ... )`, which is a *zero-width lookahead assertion*—a nice way of saying that the stuff within should follow what we've matched so far, but we don't actually consume it.

The `(?!\d)` says that a `\d` (i.e. number) should *not* follow, so in total:

- `(\d)` find and capture a number.
- `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` assert that one or more groups of three digits should follow, but they should not have yet another digit following them all.

We replace with `"$1,"`, i.e. the first number captured and a comma.

As a result, we place commas after digits which have multiples of three digits following, which is a nice way to say we add commas as thousand separators!

Answer (score 1):

`?!` means **Negative lookahead** , it is used to match something not followed by something else, in your case a **digit**